# Bootstrap - Hover Popover Flickering with data-container=body also

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am using Bootstrap plugin with jQuery.

Having issues with Hover Flickering for Bootstrap Popover... I have tried with below options but issue is still exists

Options Tried:

1. `$('.article-content').popover();`
2. `$( document ).ready(function() { $('.article-content2').popover(); });`
3. `data-container="body"`

### HTML

```
<article>

<span class="article-content" href="#" data-content="Popover with Hover" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Mouse Over</span>        
<span class="article-content2" href="#" data-content="Popover with with Document Ready" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title 2" data-trigger="hover">Mouse Over with Document Ready</span>        
<span class="article-content2" href="#" data-content="Popover with with Document Ready &amp; data-container=body" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title 3" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body">Mouse Over with Document Ready &amp; data-container="body"</span>

</article>
```

### CSS

```
body{margin:50px;}    
article span{background:#ddd;width:100%;float:left;border-top:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;margin-bottom:1px;}
```

### jQuery

```
$('.article-content').popover();

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.article-content2').popover();
});
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zpgs5d23/1/)

Thanks to  @mijopabe, We just need to add "**fade**" CSS class if we do not have one. Exactly dont know the relation, but it works like a Champ.

### [HERE IS WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zpgs5d23/8/)

### CSS Class to be Added Extra to Remove Flickering

```
.fade {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0s linear;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0s linear;
       -ms-transition: opacity 0s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0s linear;
           transition: opacity 0s linear;
 }
```

Comment: Your fiddle needs Bootstrap

Comment: Sorry... updated the fiddle (**http://jsfiddle.net/zpgs5d23/1/**)

Comment: Try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/zpgs5d23/6/) I don't see a flicker when spacing the items apart. The flicker could be caused by moving your mouse over two items that have a div between them that is not a target for the popover so it's jumping back and forth. I would remove margin-bottom entirely.

Comment: Thanks and its working like a champ in my local machine... :) But when I see the same in my application which is inside iFrame, I am still getting the flickering :(... Is it because of iFrame or <DOCTYPE> -- (DOCTYPE I am using HTML5 standard) I am not sure...

Comment: Okay.. I got it now.. But not sure how it works. If I add "**fade**" css class it is working exactly in a way what I want...  Appreciate your effor

Comment: No problem, happy to hear it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the flickering issue on hover you can add this class on the popover

```
.popover{ pointer-events:none; }
```

Refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20289#issuecomment-442995935) for more info